# Making token accessible to other views after being set in class

Tags: angular

I have an angular 2 project where I want to make an api call and grab a token. Then I want to set the token in a property within that class.

I want to then be able to grab that token from other parts of my app.

This may be a simple question, but once I set that property, is it always available to other classes as someone goes from view-to-view?

Comment: The best way would be to hold it within a service, and make sure that service is provided at the root level

Comment: Thanks user184994. By providing it at the root level, do you mean adding it to the the app.modules.ts? And if I set the property, will the updated token simply be available if I import {} the module and reference the property in another component?

Comment: Yep, add it to the `providers` array in app.module. Then, if you add the service into your components constructor (i.e. make use of depedency injection), then the updated token will be available

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a shared `service` (class, that you are referring) and then

1. Set a value of token to some class property.
2. Provide service in `AppModule`
3. Inject the `service` in all the `components`, where you want to access the service `property`.
4. Access `service` property in `component` view using service object created during DI.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2pgxt)